# Whitespace differences with output

Tags: batch-file

I have written a script to generate a `.CSV` file from an `SQLCMD` query, but when I open it in Notepad, there is unwanted spacing between data. When I manually paste the query results in the `.csv` file then there is no spacing when I open it in `Notepad`.

Please do let me know, what should I do to avoid the issue.

My minimal script example:

```
set destfolder="c:\Test"
SQLCMD -s "--Database name--" -d Audit -E -I -i "C:\Test\Mandates.sql" -s "," -o "c:\Test\tempfile.csv"
findstr /v /c:"---" "c:\Test\tempfile.csv" > "%destfolder%\%filename%"
del "%destfolder%\tempfile.csv"
```

Issue:

```
CustomerName,CustomerNumber,Value
Adam,        123456789,     0
```

Expected:

```
CustomerName,CustomerNumber,Value
Adam,123456789,0
```

Comment: Please take a look at [Ask] and offer a [MCVE]. What do you mean with "*Q1- why -h is used?*". Please provide (a part) of your script (use the correct formatting). Also refine the Issue/Expected output (is there really a row index, like `1.`?). Why are you not just using the [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-6) or [`Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) cmdlets?

Comment: That isn't Powershell.

Comment: I don't see '-h' anywhere in that script so your Q1 still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You have shown us, _(in your code)_, how you generate the output directly to the file which you subsequently open in Notepad and which looks like that shown under `Issue:`. Can you please explain the 'manually paste' process and how that is relevant to your question.

Comment: …also, is there a reason you're not using [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility)?

Comment: By manual paste process I mean, we run this query daily->Then copy the result with headers and paste in excel and save it as .csv file. In that case we will get the expected output. But if the data is extracted and copied in the location by the batch process, it will give me the output mentioned as in Issue and as a result the file size is 3-4 times than actually "manually pasted" one.

Comment: I have no idea about `bcp`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

```
SQLCMD -s "--Database name--" -d Audit -E -I -W -i "C:\Test\Mandates.sql" -s "," -o "c:\Test\tempfile.csv"
```

I have used -W in the above script which resolves the issue. Thanks